# Import selected data from .txt in tikz

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Like I said in the title, I struggle with the import of data.
The experimental data, that I get, is in a .txt file and has the following structure:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx

yyyyyyyyyyy

zzzzzzzzzzz

N   a   b   c    
1 3 4 5       
2 6 7 8        
3 9 8 7        
4 6 5 4   

xxxxxxxxxxx

yyyyyyyyyyy

zzzzzzzzzzz
```

x,y and z is text that is not used in the plot, so I want to skip the lines on the top and bottom of the file - only the table is important. **Right now I have to remove those lines by hand to use the code below**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,xcolor=dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\large}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
\addplot table [y=c,x=b]{mydata.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Something else I would like to know is: can i perform a simple calculation?
Because I want to plot the negative values of the row "**b**" from mydata.txt

For example like this:

....

```
\addplot table [y=c,x=g]{mydata.txt};
```

with g=b*(-1)

....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For the "something else" see `x expr`/`y expr`, e.g. `\addplot table[y=c,x expr=-\thisrow{b}] {mydata.txt}`. Skipping the first few lines is simple enough, search the `pgfplots` manual for `skip first n`, I think something like `\addplot table[x=a,y=b,skip first n=10]{mydata.txt};` would skip the first 10 lines, for example. (Untested, never used that key myself.) Don't know how to skip the last part of the file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Torbjørn T. already mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334352/import-selected-data-from-txt-in-tikz#comment819606_334352) you can use `x expr` and `y expr` to do some mathematical stuff with your table values.

He also already mentioned one method where starting rows are ignored which is `skip first n`. Another method would be to assign a comment character to the lines *before* the actual table start, which will also work for the rows *after* the table. But I don't know of any key to ignore *non-table* lines.

```
    \begin{filecontents}{testOne.txt}
        I am a header line
        without a comment character

        a   b
        1   2
        2   3
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{testTwo.txt}
        % I am a header line
        % with a comment character
        %
        a   b
        2   4
        3   5
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{testThree.txt}
        a   b
        3   6
        4   7
        %
        % I am a bottom line
        % with a comment character
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{testFour.txt}
        a   b
        3   6
        4   7

        I am a bottom line
        without a comment character
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            % these three work fine
            \addplot table [skip first n=3] {testOne.txt};
            \addplot table [x=a,y expr=-\thisrow{b}] {testTwo.txt};
            \addplot table {testThree.txt};

%            % this will lead to an error, because PGFPlots first tries to read
%            % the table before skipping the given indices
%            \addplot table [skip coords between index={2}{4}] {testFour.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]